# Implementing a RESTful service

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, jax-rs

I'm building a web service to support an Android e-reader app I'm making for our campus magazine. The service needs to return `issue` objects to the app, each of which has a cover image and a collection of articles to be displayed. I'd like some general input on two strategies I'm considering, and/or some specific help on a few issues I'm having with them:

- Strategy 1: Have 2 DB tables, `Issues` and `Articles`: The `Issues` table contains simply an `int id`, `varchar name` and `varchar imageURI`. `Articles` contains many more columns (headline, content, blurb, etc.), with each article on a separate row. One of the columns is `issueID`, which points to the issue to which the article belongs. When issue number n is requested, the service first pulls its data from the `Issues` table and uses it to create a new Issue object. The constructor instantiates a new `List<Article>` as an instance variable and populates it by pulling all articles with the matching issueID from the `Articles` table. What I can't figure out with this option is exactly how to execute it at a single endpoint, so that app only has to create one HTTP connection to get everything it needs for the issue (or is this not as important as I think it is?).
- Have a single `Issues` table with the `id`, `name`, and `imageURI` columns, plus a large number of additional `text Article1... text Article40` columns. The Articles are packaged into JSONObjects before being uploaded to the server, and these JSONObjects (which will be very long) are stored directly in the database. My worry here is that the text files will be too long, plus I have a nagging suspicion that this strategy isn't in line with best practices (although I can't put my finger on why...)

Also, This being my first web service, and given the requirements specified above, would it be advisable to use the Spring (or some other) framework or am I better off just using JAX-RS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 questions here

1. How to convert your objects to JSON and expose them with a rest service.
2. How to store/retrieve your data.

To implement your webservices, Jersey is my favorite option. It is the open-source reference implementation of the JSR 311 (JAX-RS). In addition, Jersey uses Jackson to automatically handle the JSON/Object mapping.

To store your data, your second option... is clearly not an option :)
The first solution seems viable.
IMHO, as your application seems tiny, you should not put in place JPA/Hibernate etc.You should simply make one request by hand with a JOIN between Issues and Article, populate the requested Issue then let Jackson automatically convert your object to JSON.